# Clear textarea and reset character count of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area. Underneath the text area I can display the count of the characters in the text area as the user types.

I also have a button for the user to clear the contents of the text area.

The issue I have and I am baffled by is that when the user clicks on the clear button, the text area is cleared, but the character count remains at the previous count, when actually the count should be zero.

I have used **keyup focus blur change** in the bind, but the character count still does not change when the user clicks on the clear button. The display of the count does not return to zero, until I focus in the text area with the mouse.

**Any suggestions?**

Here is my HTML code:

```
<textarea cols="40" id="id_objective_details" maxlength="1000" name="objective_details" rows="10">Test</textarea>

<span id="id_char_count"></span><span> of 1,000 character limit</span>

<i id="id_icon_reset" class="fa fa-ban blue_color icon_size20" rel="tooltip" html="true" data-placement="top" onclick="resetCharacterCount();focusTextArea();" title="Clear"></i>
```

Here is the JS / JQ code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind displaying the character count of the text area to the keyup event (function on base.html).
    displayCharacterCount('id_objective_details', 'id_char_count');
}

function displayCharacterCount(id1, id2) {
    $('#' + id1).bind("keyup focus blur change", function () {
        numeral.language('{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}');
        var charCount = numeral($(this).val().length).format('0,0');
        $("#" + id2).text(charCount);
    });
}

function resetCharacterCount() {
    displayCharacterCount('id_objective_details', 'id_char_count');
}

function focusTextArea() {
    $('#id_objective_details').focus();
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question is a working snippet so we can see where is the problem? What is "numeral"?

Answer (score 0):

I notice a few problems in your code. First you are not resetting the textarea when you click the `clear`. Second, you are binding a new event handler each time you call `resetCharacterCount()`.

You should create a method that is responsible only for re-calculating the text count and display it. And you bind the events to textarea only on start up. Here is a working example: (Note that I don't know what `numberal` is, but I believe it is formatting the word count, so all I did is to comment it up)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind displaying the character count of the text area to the keyup event (function on base.html).
    var id_objective_details_elem = $('#id_objective_details');
    // bind the event
    bindCharacterCount('id_objective_details', 'id_char_count');
    // calculate the word count on setup
    displayCharacterCount.call(id_objective_details_elem, 'id_char_count');
    // bind onClick event to reset button
    $('#id_icon_reset').click(function(e) {
        // clear the text in textarea
        id_objective_details_elem.text('');
        resetCharacterCount()
        focusTextArea();
    });
});

function displayCharacterCount(id2) {
    var charCount = $(this).val().length;
    // uncomment the following line in your production project
    // numeral.language('{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}');
    // var charCount = numeral($(this).val().length).format('0,0');
    $("#" + id2).text(charCount);
}

function bindCharacterCount(id1, id2) {
    $('#' + id1).bind("keyup focus blur change", function () {
        displayCharacterCount.call(this, id2);
    });
}

function resetCharacterCount() {
    // instead of binding the events again, directly call displayCharacterCount
    displayCharacterCount.call($('#id_objective_details'), 'id_char_count');
}

function focusTextArea() {
    $('#id_objective_details').focus();
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ah7Lywg/

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it's work!

```
<textarea cols="40" id="id_objective_details" maxlength="1000" name="objective_details" rows="10">Test</textarea>

<span id="id_char_count"></span><span> of 1,000 character limit</span>

<i id="id_icon_reset" class="fa fa-ban blue_color icon_size20" rel="tooltip" html="true" data-placement="top" onclick="resetCharacterCount();focusTextArea();" title="Clear">clear</i>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_objective_details').keyup(function(){
        $('#id_char_count').text($('#id_objective_details').val().length);
    });
});

function resetCharacterCount() {
    $('#id_char_count').text(0);
    $('#id_objective_details').val('');
}

function focusTextArea() {
    $('#id_objective_details').focus();
}
</script>
```