# how to reset a character count to zero when textarea is empty in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to reset the character count back to zero when the textarea field is empty in jQuery. I've been able to add the character count using the below code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').on('keyup', function(event) {
        var text = this.value.length;
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
          $('#char-count-val').text(text);
        }else {
           $('#char-count-val').text('0');
        }
   });
});
```

Not sure why it won't reset to zero (0). I tried the [solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450751/clear-textarea-and-reset-character-count-of-textarea) but still doesn't work to me. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic works fine with the keyboard, but as you're using a key-based event, if you interact with the field using the mouse the event won't be fired, so the count will be incorrect.

To fix this, and improve the UX due to the count being updated quicker, use the `input` event instead:

```js
$('#content').on('input', function(event) {
  var len = this.value.length;
  $('#char-count-val').text(len);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="content"></textarea>
<div id="char-count-val"></div>
```

Comment: Works flawlessly and i love the fact that it updated the clear character on the fly. i'm trying to implement this for word count and its not resetting back to 0.  `var word_len = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length; $('#char-count-val').text(word_len ); ` .. Please @Rory McCrossan What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. i simplified a bit..

```js
var lengthInput = 0; // or lengthInput = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').on('keyup', function(event) {
        lengthInput = this.value.length;
        $('#char-count-val').text(lengthInput);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="content"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<p>Count : <span id="char-count-val" style="color:#fd0000;">0</span></p>
```

good codes

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason but @Rory McCrossan version worked